# How to exclude TaxonomyFieldControl from spell checker

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, page-layout, publishing-page, taxonomyfieldvalue

I have a page layout with a couple of `TaxonomyFieldControls` on it.  When I run the spell checker in the ribbon the taxonomy fields are getting flagged with spelling errors.  I don't want the taxonomy fields to be included in the spell check.

I solved this problem for the `UserField` control (People Picker) and the `SPFieldTargetToControl` control (Audience Targeting) by using javascript to add the class "`ms-spellcheck-false`" and setting the attribute "`excludeFromSpellCheck`" to true for the html elements generated by those controls.  However, the same fix does not work for the `TaxonomyFieldControl`.

Has anybody run into this and found a solution?

Comment: have you tried this? https://cann0nf0dder.wordpress.com/category/development/page/4/

Comment: That post is useful for sharepoint controls that render textareas and inputs.  The TaxonomyFieldControl renders an input control but also some spans.  The spans are being checked by the spell checker as well.  Applying the class "ms-spellcheck-false" and adding the "excludeFromSpellCheck" attribute to the span don't seem to prevent the spell checker from processing the contents.